# Searching a lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, cascading

I have a lookup which looks at a list of clients and project numbers, and is rather large (around 500 and growing), and I was wondering if there was anyway to search the results of the list lookup rather than just having one giant dropdown?

Prefer an OOTB solution if possible as we're using Sharepoint online (365)

The other option would be to have a cascading list so that we could choose 'Client A' and then only see related projects in the next drop down for client A - but again this seems to involve 3rd party addons/behind the scenes code.

This lookup will be used on multiple lists eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution to my problem (although it's a 3rd party, it's not too expensive) by [enter link description here](https://plumsail.com/cross-site-lookup/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if anyone else needs a native solution, this can be accomplished using client-side scripting. [SPServices has a cascading lookup](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) function that will allow you to start typing your selection and will take you to that entry in the dropdown.